# Angular - Json POST another table key

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have 2 database tables like that;

- [image]

I have created 2 firms with JSON POST. I want to create users too. But i get "status 500" error. I know that's about data type of firm.id. I have tried post as number, Firm object, string. But none of them is working well.

Form post function;

```
firm:Firm;
myDate = new Date();
onSubmit(user: User){  
 user.created_at = this.myDate;
 user.updated_at = this.myDate;
 user.firm = this.firm;
 console.log(user);
 this.dataService.addUser(user).subscribe(stat => {console.log(stat)});
}
```

Console;

- [image]

Object, number, string... no one works for firm. Anyone knows how could I post data with other table id?

Comment: `user.firm = this.firm.id;` firm column in user table is a foreign key to primary key of firm table. You need table id

Comment: I have tried that too.